# Powershell sometimes outputs full Path and sometimes relative Path

Tags: powershell

I have a script that gets some lines from a txt file, and then splits them to get a specific part of the line, the problem is that, my problem is that im using double dot (:) as a delimiter, and sometimes powershell will output the full path of the file, and sometimes it will just output the relative path.

So when im trying to split something like this

```
sometext.txt:2:1;2
```

and instead i get this

```
C:\Tester\folder\sometext.txt:2:1;2
```

if im using this line of code

```
$z=$z.split(':')[1]
```

you can see how badly this will turn out.
I want it to output either the full path or relative path consistently.
Here is the block of code related to the problem

```
$z=(Select-String -Path "sometext.txt" -Pattern "\b$D;$Z\b" | Select-object -First 1)
$z=$z | Out-String
$z=$z.split(':')[1]
```

Comment: i expect this ```sometext.txt:2:1;2```

Comment: Are you using `Get-Item` to get the file path to begin with? If so you could just do something like `$name = Get-Item -Path sometext.txt | %{$_.Name}` for the relative path and `$name = Get-Item -Path sometext.txt | %{$_.FullName}` for the full path

Comment: You can use `-replace` for this. `'C:\Tester\folder\sometext.txt:2:1;2' -replace '.*\\'` or `$z -replace '.*\\'`.

Comment: No,  the file im trying to acess is in the same folder as the script, thats why in -Path i only specify the file name not the Path

Comment: Can you show where the path is coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use take the leaf of [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-6) to get the relative path consistently:

```
PS C:\> Split-Path "sometext.txt:2:1;2" -leaf                                                             
sometext.txt:2:1;2
PS C:\> Split-Path "C:\Tester\folder\sometext.txt:2:1;2" -leaf                                            
sometext.txt:2:1;2
```